# Spread Toolkit, how does it work?

Tags: spread-toolkit

I'm trying to read up on and understand how SPREAD toolkit works. Maybe i'm not really good at understanding some of these documents.

How does a machine send a message out to other machines? Does it have like a central machine controlling and directing the messages? The document says that there are 3 link protocols(link/TCP/HOP), so if it's a ring protocol, a broadcast message means that a message from one machine will be passed from one machine to the next in a ring?

If most of the time i simply wish to broadcast messages to everyone, but in certain situations if i wish to only send messages to a few machines, do i just join the machines to a group, or is there other ways to do it?

Thanks